# Weird C# namespace issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

I've got a project with several namespaces and many classes contained within one of them ->

```
Some.Namepsace. (namespace)
               ExistingClass (class)
               ExistingClass2 (class)
               Constants (class)
                        .Enum (enum)
```

Within this project I created a class, but with an incorrect namespace like so

```
namespace Some.Namespace.Some.Namespace
{
    public class NewClass {}
}
```

Now **Some.Namespace.ExistingClass** cannot resolve a reference to **Some.Namespace.Constants.Enum** - it appears to be looking for Some.Namespace.Some.Namespace.Constants.Enum.

Any idea why? **NewClass** does not reference anything, and is not referenced by anything so I don't see how it's namespace could affect any other components. I fixed the namespace issue on **NewClass**, and that fixes it.

Comment: Are you saying that it works now and you just wanted to know why it happened or it still doesn't work with the fixed namespace?

Comment: Works now, just wanted to know why

Comment: I am having a great deal of difficulty understanding your descriptive essay of what the relationships between all the types and namespaces are. How about you just give us a little repro of the problem?  What does the code look like?

Comment: How's that Eric? It's always clear when you're posting the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must have something to do with the way C# in visual studio/csc attempts to resolve references. It would appear it goes something like this:

- Look relative to the namespace of the calling object
- If such a namespace is not found, attempt to look up the reference as if it's absolute

In my case, before I added `Some.Namespace.Some.Namespace.NewClass`, when VS tried to resolve the reference from `Some.Namespace.ExistingClass` to `Some.Namespace.Constants.Enum`, it first attempted a relative namespace lookup (starting from ExistingClasse's `Some.Namespace`), found no such namespace. It then attempted an absolute lookup and found it.

After I added `Some.Namespace.Some.Namespace.NewClass`, it found the namespace, noticed the object was not there, and decided to discontinue searching.

Answer (score 6):

A class inside **Some.Namespace.Some.Namespace** will try to resolve **Some.Namespace.Constants.Enum** 
as: **Some.Namespace.Some.Namespace.Constants.Enum**, not **Some.Namespace.Constants.Enum**.

It would work if you tried to refer to the Enum as: **global::Some.Namespace.Constants.Enum**.

Comment: nice clear answer, which does not answer my originally muddled question. I cleared up my question.